# How to remove bytes from a byte array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have a program that has a byte array that varies in size, but is around 2300 bytes. What I want to do is create a function that will create a new byte array, removing all bytes that I pass to it. For example:

```
byte[] NewArray = RemoveBytes(OldArray,0xFF);
```

I need a function that will remove any bytes equal to 0xFF and return me a new byte array.

Any help would be appreciated. I am using C#, by the way.

Comment: if it varies in size, it's more of a collection than an array.  But I understand the need to use arrays to emulate the collection for use with older apis.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) extension method to filter the array:

```
byte[] newArray = oldArray.Where(b => b != 0xff).ToArray();
```

or if you want to remove multiple elements you could use the [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) extension method:

```
byte[] newArray = oldArray.Except(new byte[] { 0xff, 0xaa }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Concise. Super helpful.

Comment: Note, `Except` is the set difference. So every remaining byte is only returned one time. In my case `printData.Except(bytesToRemove).ToArray()` doesn't get the expected output, while `printData.Where(e => bytesToRemove.All(b => b != e)).ToArray()` works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Break the problem down:

Can you write code to copy from one array to another?

Can you write a conditional?

Can you allocate a new array?

If you are stuck on one of these then ask specifically about it.